# convert dd-mm date format to dd-month format in Mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]I have Employees date-of-birth in dd/mm format and from this details i need to find employee's whose birthday is today,tomorrow and day after tomorrow and the Emp_dob column must display date in this format(eg: Employee's birthday is today then 09-NOV).

below is mysql query

```html
SELECT 
    Emp_Name,Emp_Department,
    Emp_DOB
    FROM mldob.tbl_mldobtest WHERE  
        Emp_DOB IN (
          DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%d-%m'),
          DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d-%m'),
          DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+INTERVAL 2 DAY,'%d-%m')
      )
      order by tbl_mldobtest.Emp_DOB;
```

the problem is EMP_DOB column displays dob in 09-11 format but i need in 09-Nov format

so can anybody please guide me how to achieve this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does this conversion has to happen in MySQL? You are not using any kind of language (php, ruby, python, java) to connect to MySQL?

Comment: i m using jsp to connect with database and fetch data and display

Comment: So why don't you format the date there according to your needs?

Comment: What is the column definition for Emp_DOB?  Is 9th November stored as '09/11' or '09-11' as your formatting of the query suggests?

Comment: hi its stored as 09-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, didn't pay attention to DOB only holding day/month instead of full date.

Assuming Emp_DOB is CHAR(5) held as e.g. '09-11'

```
SELECT Emp_Name, Emp_Department, DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y'), '-', SUBSTRING(Emp_DOB,4,2), '-', SUBSTRING(Emp_DOB,1,2)), '%d-%b')
FROM tbl_mldobtest
WHERE Emp_DOB IN (
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%d-%m'),
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d-%m'),
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+INTERVAL 2 DAY,'%d-%m')
)
ORDER BY Emp_DOB;
```

If you hold Emp_DOB as a date (as I originally assumed) then this will do what you want, no need to format dates in where clause:

```
SELECT Emp_Name, Emp_Department, DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB, '%d-%b')
FROM tbl_mldobtest
WHERE DATE(Emp_DOB) BETWEEN DATE(CURDATE()) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))
ORDER BY Emp_DOB;
```

Comment: Hi above query displays birthday's of 11-sep,11-oct,11-nov in the specified format

Comment: Sorry, substrings were wrong way round!  Now fixed.

Comment: If you want month in upper case then use UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y'), '-', SUBSTRING(Emp_DOB,4,2), '-', SUBSTRING(Emp_DOB,1,2)), '%d-%b')) in select.

Answer (score 0):

The format for the abbreviated month name is '%b', not '%m'

Answer (score 0):

Try below format

`DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d-%b')`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT 
    Emp_Name,Emp_Department,
    DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB, '%e%a') as emp_dob
    FROM mldob.tbl_mldobtest WHERE  
        Emp_DOB IN (
          DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%d-%m'),
          DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d-%m'),
          DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+INTERVAL 2 DAY,'%d-%m')
      )
      order by tbl_mldobtest.Emp_DOB;
```

Also you can refer mysql date functions

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/

Comment: Hi, the above query fetches the employees whose birthday is today,tomorrow and day after but EMP_DOB column shows null

Comment: hi , you can check table above near question

Comment: I mean the real table not the output

Comment: Actual table contains 3500 rows of data so cant be shared

Comment: How is date stored in your table is it in datetime format ? can you select only 2 rows that are not null using query select * from tbl_mldobtest limit 2

Comment: hi the data type for EMP_DOB column is varchar(45)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127707/discussion-between-atul-mishra-and-heena-ramesh).

Answer (score -1):

replace all %m in your sql with %b